# Low Quality Review Queue, meaning of Looks OK?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was going through the Low Quality Review Queue and looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866595/how-does-an-equal-to-expression-work-in-a-printf-placeholder) which is clearly wrong, and has been downvoted heavily.

Looking through the delete reasons, there isn't one for just being plain wrong.  So I suppose that means it's inappropriate to recommend it for deletion, and I don't have any other good options besides Edit (which would radically change the meaning), Delete (which doesn't seem appropriate) and Skip (which leaves it in the queue for the next person to scratch their head.)

So two questions:

1. Since it is downvoted, and has been pointed out as being clearly wrong, and being wrong doesn't seem to be a delete reason, would it be appropriate to tick "Looks OK" in this instance?
2. Am I right in assuming that the low quality queue primarily about recommending low quality posts for deletion or bringing attention to salvageable questions and answers for editing?  Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Incorrectness is not a reason for deletion through the Low Quality queue. "Looks OK" is the appropriate response.

Comment: In that case, would it be a Good Thing to rename the "Looks OK" button to "Deletion not appropriate" or something a bit more explicit?  "Looks OK" makes me think: "This post isn't actually low quality."  Rather than: "This post should be allowed to survive."

Comment: As long as everyone chooses the right answer, then this good. But you could fail an audit if not careful. The automated audits do not know if that was the right choice.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity, I agree but at least we don't have to hit "Looks good" anymore, baby steps

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity "Low Quality" in the context of Stack Exchange has nothing to do with correctness. "Looks OK" *does* mean "This post isn't actually low quality." Just because something is incorrect doesn't mean it's low quality - it means it's incorrect. They're not synonyms. If *you* happen to know something is incorrect, you're more than welcome to visit the post and downvote it separately.

Comment: @animuson, If that's how it's defined then that's fine.  I just found it confusing, and I'm pretty sure I wouldn't be the only one.  Quality is a rather subjective word, and without guidance it's very easy to conflate standard notions of quality and SE quality guidelines.

Comment: @animuson: We should be able to downvote from within the queue then. Also, a tutorial for flagging would be nice or recommending deletion would be nice.

Comment: @staticx, oh please let's not start THAT argument. :(

Answer (score 4):

`"Looks Ok"` is really a synonym for `"Neither delete, edit, nor skip"`

Click `"Looks Ok"` if you don't think that the post needs to be deleted, if you're not entirely sure how to edit it, and your not quite so uncertain about what's going on that you need to skip.

Don't judge correctness in the LQP queue.  Upvotes, Downvotes, and comments are how you give feedback on correctness