# Change text of "Looks OK" button in Low Quality queue

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, user-interface

In the Low Quality review queue, you are presented with the following options:

[image: Low Quality review queue buttons]

I have seen confusion about the intended meaning of "Looks OK" a few times here on Meta. A couple of examples:

- [Low Quality Review Queue, meaning of Looks OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266428/low-quality-review-queue-meaning-of-looks-ok)
- [How to review low quality answers which are not crap but just incorrect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278436/how-to-review-low-quality-answers-which-are-not-crap-but-just-incorrect?cb=1)

This has led me to the following thoughts.

- If someone flagged it as low quality (even incorrectly), the post is very likely to have *some* sort of serious problem, perhaps factual or grammatical or something else.
- There is no option in the interface for indicating that the post has problems but should not be deleted. I suppose you might argue that the user should Edit in those cases, but there would be many cases where editing out the problem would change the meaning of the post too much.
- From reading other posts here on Meta, it seems like the "correct" thing to do in those cases is choose "Looks OK," possibly downvoting and then leaving a comment or taking other appropriate action outside of the queue.
- In the face of serious problems, the post most certainly does not "look OK," as the phrase is commonly understood. As a result, this choice seems wrong.

In light of that, I don't think the name "Looks OK" makes very much sense. The label on the button should more accurately reflect its intended usage.

My preliminary suggestion for a new name is simply:

**Don't Delete**

I believe this more accurately reflects how the button is intended to be used. Even though the post may have serious flaws, it makes perfect sense to say, "Deletion is not the appropriate response to the problems in this post." The user is then free to decline the flag and then take some other appropriate action, without feeling like they're giving the post any kind of stamp of approval. This will lead to more correct understanding and usage of the queue.

This should be a low effort change, as well, since it's only text on a button.

**Edit:**

[This past answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232342/216712) that explains why the "Looks OK" option was chosen has been brought to my attention. However, I do not believe this request to be a duplicate.

- The other thread in question has been completed. A change was made based on the feedback, and the change made is not currently satisfactory, for the reasons I outlined above.
- The answer argues for the deletion of content that's bad for some reason other than the current intended usage of the queue. This is in opposition to the instructions we're currently receiving about how to use the queue. That raises three possibilities:

  1. Shog's answer there was in opposition to policy. (Unlikely, in my opinion.)
  2. Policy has since changed, making the reasoning presented there no longer relevant.
  3. We're getting bad advice on how to use the queue.

In the first two cases, I think the reasoning I've outline is still valid, and this request should go through. In the last case, some serious correction is needed, as it means we're being misinformed about policy. Additionally, if our current understanding of policy is wrong, then changing nothing will still leave users confused about the queue. If the Low Quality queue *should* be used for factually incorrect/poorly worded/poorly formatted/poor mechanics, then the options *need* to be expanded to allow users to do more with the post. I consider the lack of additional options evidence that our understanding of the queue is correct.

Comment: How about "No Action Needed"? BTW: It was "Looks Good" earlier.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, I found the thread where it got changed to "Looks OK" when I was looking to see if this had already been proposed. (Although, I can't seem to find it now.) As for "No Action Needed," as I laid out, additional action outside the queue is often needed. "No Action Needed" seems to be mildly in conflict with that fact (though much, much less so than "Looks OK").

Comment: +1 That bugged me too, just was never important enough as I know what it means in the context. But yeah, "Don't delete" would be great!

Comment: I'm afraid that Shog already [*answered* this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232342/178576).

Comment: @Vyktor Shog's answer there is no longer applicable. The statement, "Well, I want stuff that doesn't look good deleted!" is in sharp contrast to the current expectations of how we're supposed to use the Queue. Either Shog was in opposition to policy at the time or the policies have since changed. Additionally, the option I present here *is* less confusing that the options he suggests.

Comment: @jpmc26 I do appreciate how you've incorporated why is past question different from yours, that's how things should be done around here. Thanks.

Comment: Similar suggestion on stack exchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258249/change-wording-of-looks-ok-on-low-quality-post-review-option

Answer (score 44):

I came to Meta today to raise this exact issue.

My question was going to be "So, do you click 'looks ok' or 'recommend delete' when the question needs a downvote, but not deletion?

Because it neither looks OK, nor does it meet the criteria for delete.

So I totally support "Don't Delete", or similar sentiment.

I'd also like to be able to downvote from that review page (assuming this is a legitimate thing to do?)

Comment: Ever since I hit 2k I've wanted to vote on a question in the review queue. I would love to see this raised as a separate issue.

Comment: @McAdam331 There is a separate feature request for downvoting in the LQ queue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228738/add-downvote-option-to-low-quality-review-queue-list-of-potential-actions. I tend to agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: @jpmc26 thanks I'll head over there. It doesn't always have to be a downvote, either. Sometimes when I review suggested edits I realized someone cleaned up a really good question, and I can't upvote that question either.

Answer (score 16):

I think having a negative statement on a button is not very user friendly. Normally, a button performs an action, and the button text should communicate what that action is. If it says "Don't Delete", you click the button to **not** perform a certain action ("Delete"), which seems more complicated than it needs to be.

My simple suggestion for the button text:

## Keep

Answer (score 2):

Another possible name of the button

**May be useful**

When reviewer will click it, options to add comments could be added, similar to some Delete options, e.g.

> This is a link-only answer
>
> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the
> answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can
> become invalid if the linked page changes.”“While this link may answer