# Does this answer contain spam?

Tags: support, answers, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, spam

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22696329). The system said the answer was spam.

[image]

Can somebody explain why this answer was deleted as spam? I'm not familiar with awk, cut, or sed, but their tag info looks suitable for POSIX questions.

Comment: Looks like this particular post has a [troubled past](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55143530/revisions) ([10k+ screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HwKs.png))... audits can be iffy sometimes. There was likely a good reason the post and user were deleted, but that post probably shouldn't become a review audit.

Comment: You're not the [only one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22479444) that this happened to

Comment: The post has been [used as an audit in the low quality posts queue 4 times after being deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55143530/timeline). The users have split 2/2 between "Looks OK" and "Recommend Deletion".

Comment: I've just undeleted and deleted the post, which should make it ineligible as a review audit.

Comment: Disregards of poor audit.. when doing reviews you have to be confident in both: question and answer. I guess question was chosen based on tags you know, but *"I'm not familiar with awk, cut, or sed, but their tag info looks suitable for POSIX questions"* imply you should not be clicking "Looks OK" anyway. When in doubts you can go to question and check everything carefully there.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The post itself is **not spam**.

A moderator flagged the post as spam because it was posted by a known troll account, and the moderator wanted to apply the system-level spam penalties to that account.

Unfortunately, the spam flag *also* made the system believe that the post itself was spam, and thus the system started using it as a review audit for unsuspecting users, such as yourself. That was a mistake. [Sam has now corrected that mistake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382622/does-this-answer-contain-spam#comment686190_382622).

However…it's not a good answer, and "Looks OK" was still the wrong decision in review. Why? Look again. The question asks for a way to get the numeric version of the timezone (by which is meant, the offset from UTC). The answer essentially says, "You can get and parse it yourself using a tool." This is not a useful answer. The answer itself does not contain the solution to the problem. (How do I use that tool to parse it?)

*Any* action other than "Looks OK" would have been appropriate—editing, recommending deletion or skipping. If you weren't sure because you don't have much knowledge about POSIX shell utilities, then "Skip" would have been a good choice. It is always the safe choice.

Comment: Okay, you are right, I had to look with more attention and see that recommendation to use some tools is not complete and useful answer.

Comment: Downvoting and flagging are not available in "Low quality" review. The possible actions are "Edit", "Recommend deletion", "Skip". This supports my belief that review is not expected to verify technical correctness of post, but rather to detect link only answers, non answers, spam etc.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266429/113662

Comment: I'm not sure about this. The OP didn't say that they need the number *alone* (for feeding it into a script or anything). It's pretty clear what part of the output is the numeric timezone.

Comment: "You can get and parse it yourself using a tool" what do you expect from a spammer ?

Comment: @TadeuszKopec "This supports my belief that review is not expected to verify technical correctness of post, but rather to detect link only answers, non answers, **spam**" you can't flag on the low quality review queue, following your argument, spam isn't expected either.

Comment: This makes me wonder if there shouldn't be a mod-only "troll" flag that could be used to invoke network-wide penalties without mucking up the review queue.

Comment: It may not be the best answer I've ever seen but it's "good enough" IMO and certainly has value. I'd have "Looks OK"'d it (possibly adding a promptive comment) - only the author should be editing it because a continuation would be substantial.

Answer (score 17):

To add to [Cody Gray ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382623/1364007) I would also offer the following advice:

- In the Low Quality Posts review queue it's *very* useful (to the extent that I do it almost all of the time before selecting "Looks OK") to follow the `link` link on the right to see the answer in context. It might be a copy-paste duplicate of an existing answer that a user has plagiarised to parasitically gain reputation that the original post might have received, say.

  > [image: The "link" link]

  Had you followed the link you'd have seen that the answer was deleted, which would have alerted you to something fishy happening.
- A lot of LQPRQ audits (that I come across, at least) are posts from deleted users, due to the way that they are selected. This is a massive giveaway - the user is deleted, despite the post being only five days old when you performed the review:

  > [image: deleted user]

Knowing all this, you have the options of:

1. Have the courage of your convictions, and click "Looks OK" anyway and see what happens. Personally I wouldn't recommend that if you don't know what's going on (as you don't have [10k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) you don't know why it was deleted).
2. Skip the review and leave it for somebody else to deal with (assuming it's not an audit). In any review queue, if you're not sure, [**there is no shame in skipping**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/1364007). For instance, I have 217 pages of reviews in my [history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) for the Low Quality Posts review queue, but 420 pages when "show skipped reviews" is selected - i.e. I've skipped about half the reviews I've encountered.
3. Skip the review and create a [disputed-review-audits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) question on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) about it.

You ended up doing a combination of 1) and 3) - and failed the audit.

Presumably since you've not mentioned it in your answer you've not also been given a temporary automatic review ban - which is something, at least.

Comment: That's correct: they're not banned from reviewing, so this is just a warning.

Comment: another trick: click on the question score and make the +/- addition. If it doesn't match, it's an audit :)